# Parameterization of Camel Component at startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, parameter-passing

I would like to set class attributes in an Apache Camel `Component` at class instantiation. How can I do this?

I have a very simple Spring Boot Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "xyz.abc.myPackage")
public class RouteHandler_ARCHIVE {

}
```

Pulling up an Apache Camel Component residing as well in package XYZ.abc.myPackage:

```
@Component
public class Route_ARCHIVE_REST extends RouteBuilder {

    private String _deviceName;
    private String _deviceProperty;
    Set<String> _batchBuffer = new HashSet<>();
    int _batchBufferLimit = 10;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("timer:mytimer?repeatCount=1") //
                .setBody(simple("${null}")) //
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("text/event-stream"))
                .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", simple("GET"))
                .to("myUrl/" //
                    + _deviceName + "::" + _deviceProperty //
                    + "?disableStreamCache=true" //
                ) //
                .process(data -> {
                    ... my process ...
                })
                .log("${body}")
                .to(toEndpoint);
    }

}
```

I want to start multiple instances of this Route with different values of `_deviceName`, `_deviceProperty`. In the moment I only have the idea of copying the class N times and hard-code the different values - which is definitively not very efficient ;)

As I do not explicitly instantiate the `Component` class (done by `@ComponentScan`), how can I set the values of `_deviceName`, `_deviceProperty` at starting the Component? I am not insisting on having these parameters as class attributes, if it can be done differently, I'm fine too. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JavaDSL you can just define RouteDefinitions inside the loop. Just make sure each Route defintion has unique URI and RouteID.

Example (doesn't compile):

```java
public class ExampleRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        
        List<HashMap<String, String>> targets = createTargets();
        for (HashMap<String,String> target : targets) {
           configureRouteForTarget(target.get("name"), target.get("deviceName"), target.get("deviceProperty"));
        }
    }

    void configureRouteForTarget(String name, String deviceName, String deviceProperty){

        final String URI = "timer:"+ name + "?repeatCount=1";
        from(URI)
            .routeId(name+"TimerRoute")
            .setBody(constant(null))
            .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, simple("text/event-stream"))
            .setHeader("CamelHttpMethod", simple("GET"))
            .to("https://myUrl/"
                + deviceName + "::" + deviceProperty //
                + "?disableStreamCache=true" //
            ) 
            .process(data -> {
                //... my process ...
            })
            .log("${body}")
            .to("direct:someEndpoint");
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> createTargets() {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> targets = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("name", "target" + i);
            map.put("deviceName", "device" + i);
            map.put("deviceProperty", "property" + i);
        }
        return targets;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pasi, your code does the trick. One comment for those who want to do similar stuff: I maintain the configurations of devices in an "application.yml" file, so I can drive the route generation by the content of this file only. Another comment: I connect to an REST SSE service which continuously publishes data which I process with my route(s)